# how to retrieve mongodb admin password installed on AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb

3rd party developers have installed MongoDB on AWS EC2 instance and later handed over code to me.

Now I don't know what's the password for admin user of MongoDB but I do have ssh keys to connect to that EC2 instance.

My query is how to reset password for MongoDB admin user ?

Comment: Do you have credentials for MongoDB beside admin user? Does MongoDB installation is authentication enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't retrieve existing passwords, but you can reset them assuming you have `ssh` access to the host and appropriate root or `sudo` permissions to edit the MongoDB configuration and restart the MongoDB service.

The exact steps may vary depending on your O/S and how you manage the MongoDB server, but the general process for resetting a password on a standalone MongoDB server would be:

1. Take a backup of the configuration file used by your used by your MongoDB service (typically `/etc/mongod.conf` for Linux installations).
2. Edit the current configuration file to set:

   - [`security.authorization`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization) to `disabled`
   - `net.bindIp` to `localhost` (you don't want to allow remote connections while access control is disabled)
3. Restart your MongoDB service using the relevant command for your O/S (typically `sudo service mongod restart` in Linux).
4. Login to `mongod` locally without auth using the `mongo` shell: `mongo localhost/admin`.
5. Reset the password for your admin user: `db.changeUserPassword('myAdminUser','New&secur3')`.
6. Replace your MongoDB configuration file with the original that you backed up in the first step.
7. Restart the service: `sudo service mongod restart`.